# how to query google about position of webpage on keyword in django

Tags: python, django

I'm half way through creating my application. Now I don't know how to do it to the end. I want to query Google on what position the page is, on the keyword. From what to start here and what to do not to get an IP ban and not to display the recaptcha?

EDIT:

[image]

For example I have my app and added website **www.onet.pl** and keyword **wiadomości**. And now I want to ask Google on witch position  website **www.onet.pl** is on keyword **wiadomości** ? How to declare a question to google, to get the responde in value for example maximum 100 positions.?

Comment: Can you give a bit more clear description on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: RottenCandy i edited my question

Comment: how would you do that manually?

Comment: Walucas I think I need to GET keyword and compare it with website. After use Http to query google. The Google responde me a array with results. Next I have to filter and get place of keyword.